# RxJs - How to chain operations

Tags: angular, rxjs

The inner http call in the code below *this.api.one('profiles', ui.sub).get()* is not executing and I don't know why. I expected that because the inner map call returns an Observable and is wrapped by flatMap I would only need to call subscribe() once at the end but it appears I am mistaken.

```
this.$http.get(uiUri, {headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.access_token})})
    .map(resp => resp.json())
    .flatMap((ui: IID4UserInfo) => {
        let partialAccount = new Account(ui);
        partialAccount.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.currentAccount = partialAccount;
        return this.api.one('profiles', ui.sub).get().map((profile) => {
            this.currentAccount = new Account(profile.plain()); //never executes
            this.storage.set('accountService.localAccount', this.currentAccount);
            this.currentAccount.isLoggedIn = true;
            this.accountSource.next(this.currentAccount);
            if (this.loader)
                this.loader.dismiss();
            return this.currentAccount;
        }, (err) => {
            this.log.error(err);
            this.currentAccount = partialAccount;
            this.accountSource.next(partialAccount);
            if (this.loader)
                this.loader.dismiss();
            return this.currentAccount;
        })
    })
    .subscribe((profile) => {
        this.log.info('user fully loaded');
    }, err => {
        this.log.error(err)
    });
```

FYI *this.api.one('profiles', ui.sub).get()* resolves to:

```
get(queryParams?: string, headers?: any): Observable<IElement> {
    let path = queryParams ? this.currentPath + '?' + queryParams : this.currentPath;
    return this.api.http.get(path, {headers: this['_getHeaders'](headers)}).map(r => r.json()).map(resp => {
        return Object.assign(new Element(this.api, this.currentPath), resp);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can pass in an error callback in the `.map()` function. Use a `.catch()` instead:

```
this.$http.get(uiUri, {headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.access_token})})
    .map(resp => resp.json())
    .flatMap((ui: IID4UserInfo) => {
        let partialAccount = new Account(ui);
        partialAccount.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.currentAccount = partialAccount;
        return this.api.one('profiles', ui.sub)
            .get()
            .map((profile) => {
                this.currentAccount = new Account(profile.plain()); //never executes
                this.storage.set('accountService.localAccount', this.currentAccount);
                this.currentAccount.isLoggedIn = true;
                this.accountSource.next(this.currentAccount);
                if (this.loader)
                    this.loader.dismiss();
                return this.currentAccount;
            })
            //use a catch block
            .catch((err) => {
                this.log.error(err);
                this.currentAccount = partialAccount;
                this.accountSource.next(partialAccount);
                if (this.loader)
                    this.loader.dismiss();
                return this.currentAccount;
            })
    })
    .subscribe((profile) => {
        this.log.info('user fully loaded');
    }, err => {
        this.log.error(err)
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Cozy. I've updated my code but unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue. The http call is still not going out.

Comment: @Justin is `profile.plain()` an asynchronous call as well?

Comment: It's working now. The OPTIONS request sent before the GET request was timing out and I didn't catch it until I ran it under a proxy again